# pandas.core.series.Series to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and been struggling with this simple code :

So in the last line, I got the object type: pandas.core.series.Series
But this type is causing an error when I use it in 2D arrays,
how to use the 'ticker' definition to get float in my results?

I know I can simply write like this, so my result is float :

```
Volatility = sec_returns['GME'].std() * 250 ** 0.5
```

so 'GME' in the brackets instead of ticker, but I want to use ticker definition, so I can change the ticker. thank you
\

```
ticker = ['GME']
```

```
sec_data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in ticker:
    sec_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source = 'yahoo', start ='2007-01-01')['Adj Close']
```

```
sec_returns = np.log(sec_data / sec_data.shift(1))
```

```
Volatility = sec_returns[ticker].std() * 250 ** 0.5
print(Volatility)
```

```
type(Volatility)
```

```
Output: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is doing two different things when it comes to subsetting a DataFrame.

```
Volatility = sec_returns['GME'].std() * 250 ** 0.5
```

Is not the same as:

```
ticker = ['GME']
Volatility = sec_returns[ticker].std() * 250 ** 0.5
```

Because in the first instance you're subsetting by passing a string to the DataFrame with a column name and in the second you're subsetting using a lists of strings. So the second instance actually looks like this:

```
Volatility = sec_returns[['GME']].std() * 250 ** 0.5
```

This returns a `pd.Series` rather than a `float`. To get the value from the `pd.Series` you can do:

```
ticker = ['GME']
Volatility = sec_returns[ticker].std() * 250 ** 0.5
Volatility.values[0]
```

`.values` returns the series as a `numpy` array from which we retrieve the first item.

Answer (score 0):

tried all methods suggested here but sadly none worked. Instead, found this to be working:

**df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'],errors = 'coerce')**

And then check it using:

**print(df.info())**